# Array "view" on an array of different type possible?

Tags: arrays, common-lisp, undefined-behavior

Suppose, you want to create 16 bit, 32 bit, 64 bit "views" to a byte array, which behave just as if they were respectively typed arrays themselves.

The first solution coming to mind is not working (as pointed out by specification):

```
(defvar *r* (make-array 64 :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8)
                           :initial-contents
                            (loop for i below 64 collecting i)))

(defvar *r16* (make-array 32 :element-type '(unsigned-byte 16)
                             :displaced-to *r*))

; Evaluation aborted on #<SIMPLE-ERROR "Array element type of
; :DISPLACED-TO array does not match specified element type
; {10053520F3}>.
```

But it would be nice if it worked, for it would allow for very efficient lookups both in terms of bytes or words.

So, this question is asking about equally performing but working alternative ideas.

I am open to accept ffi related "hacks", if they yield what I need. CLOS solutions would probably not be "fast" enough for me.

Comment: Since this is undefined in Common Lisp, this is also implementation specific. For example on an old Lisp Machine it works and the arrays are allocated from right to left in 32bit words. Other implementations may do it differently on other machine architectures. Maybe your implementation has low-level operators to access such arrays.

Comment: @RainerJoswig I would not mind sbcl specific ideas. As this code will probably never "leave" my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two approaches to this (the second is better).

The first approach stores arrays as bytes and recreates larger quantities.  This is clearly not an ideal approach (see below for why).  This example

- knows that you want to talk 64-bit words in terms of 8-bit bytes;
- would make byte access fast and word access a little slower;
- has no optimization at all.

In real life if you want this to be fast you probably need to wire in word and byte sizes so that declarations can work.  Obviously you can and should write macros which will generate the appropriate code for you so if you change your mind you don't need to hunt down every assumption.

What this does is to store an array of 64-bit words as a 2-dimensional array of 8-bit bytes.  This makes the index arithmetic slightly easier and probably does not make access any slower (or would not if there were declarations).  But you might want to experiment just a 1-dimensional array and doing the index arithmetic yourself.  There are then accessors for 8-bit bytes and 64-bit words: it would be easy to write the intermediate ones.

What this would need to be fast is *at least* declarations and unrolling the two loops would help I expect (again, if this code is written by macros that's easy):

```
(defun 64-bit-word-array-length (a)
  (array-dimension a 0))

(defun byte-ref (a n b)
  (aref a n b))

(defun (setf byte-ref) (v a n b)
  (setf (aref a n b) v))

(defun 64-bit-word-ref (a n)
  ;; Unroll this loop in real life, add types
  (let ((v 0))
    (dotimes (c 8 v)
      (setf (ldb (byte 8 (* c 8)) v)
            (aref a n c)))))

(defun (setf 64-bit-word-ref) (v a n)
  (dotimes (c 8 v)
    (setf (aref a n c)
          (ldb (byte 8 (* c 8)) v))))

(defun make-64-bit-word-array (n &key (initial-element 0 initial-element-p))
  (let ((a (make-array (list n bytes/word)
                       :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8))))
    (when initial-element-p
      (dotimes (i n)
        (setf (64-bit-word-ref a i) initial-element)))
    a))
```

Now:

```
> (make-64-bit-word-array 2 :initial-element 999)
#2A((231 3 0 0 0 0 0 0) (231 3 0 0 0 0 0 0))

> (64-bit-word-ref (make-64-bit-word-array 2 :initial-element 999) 1)
999
```

The first approach suffers from needing to make multiple (up to 4) array references per read/store, which is a bad idea even though those array references are close to each other in memory.

So the second approach stores things as 64-bit words and then masks and shifts things out of the words.  This is a better approach because it does no more than one array reference per function call, and array references are the thing that will cost time.  This example:

- again knows that you are talking about 64-bit quantities and so on;
- has some rudimentary type declarations (but I have not checked performance at all)
- has example functions for 8, 16 and 32-bit access.

```
(deftype array-index () 
  `(integer 0 (,array-dimension-limit)))

(deftype 64-bit-word-array ()
  '(array (unsigned-byte 64) (*)))

(defun make-64-bit-word-array (n &key (initial-element 0 initial-element-p))
  (declare (type array-index n)
           (type (unsigned-byte 64) initial-element))
  (if initial-element-p
      (make-array n :element-type '(unsigned-byte 64)
                  :initial-element initial-element)
    (make-array n :element-type '(unsigned-byte 64))))

(defun 64-bit-word-array-byte-length (a)
  (declare (type 64-bit-word-array a))
  (* (array-dimension a 0) 8))

(defun 64-bit-word-array-byte-ref (a n)
  (declare (type 64-bit-word-array a)
           (type array-index n))
  (multiple-value-bind (b o) (floor n 8)
    (ldb (byte 8 (* o 8)) (aref a b))))

(defun (setf 64-bit-word-array-byte-ref) (v a n)
  (declare (type (unsigned-byte 8) v)
           (type array-index n)
           (type 64-bit-word-array a))
  (multiple-value-bind (b o) (floor n 8)
    (setf (ldb (byte 8 (* o 8)) (aref a b)) v)))

(defun 64-bit-word-array-16-bit-word-ref (a n)
  (declare (type 64-bit-word-array a)
           (type array-index n))
  (multiple-value-bind (b o) (floor n 4)
    (ldb (byte 16 (* o 16)) (aref a b))))

(defun (setf 64-bit-word-array-16-bit-word-ref) (v a n)
  (declare (type (unsigned-byte 16) v)
           (type array-index n)
           (type 64-bit-word-array a))
  (multiple-value-bind (b o) (floor n 4)
    (setf (ldb (byte 16 (* o 16)) (aref a b)) v)))


(defun 64-bit-word-array-32-bit-word-ref (a n)
  (declare (type 64-bit-word-array a)
           (type array-index n))
  (multiple-value-bind (b o) (floor n 2)
    (ldb (byte 32 (* o 32)) (aref a b))))

(defun (setf 64-bit-word-array-32-bit-word-ref) (v a n)
  (declare (type (unsigned-byte 32) v)
           (type array-index n)
           (type 64-bit-word-array a))
  (multiple-value-bind (b o) (floor n 2)
    (setf (ldb (byte 32 (* o 32)) (aref a b)) v)))
```

I think something derived from the second version should be within epsilon as fast as anything: the array accesses are what is expensive, while masking & shifting operations on immediate integers should be extremely cheap.

Comment: This answer shows what I tried to "optimize": The active conversion to and fro n-bytes to byte values as shown in the `64-bit-word-ref` family of functions. I hoped to avoid that altogether in the same sense as you would in C/C++: `uint8_t data[64]; uint64_t* data64 = &data[0];` Be it with FFI stuff or sbcl VOPS... somehow I think there should be a neat implementation just around the corner.

Comment: @BitTickler: you can't do that within a language which takes types seriously: Lisp doesn't deal with anonymous blobs of memory which sometimes mean one thing and sometimes mean another.  I've added a second version which stores things as 64-bit words and will therefore do significantly fewer memory accesses.  I'd expect an optimized version of the second approach to be within epsilon of anything else.

Comment: The second version looks promising. I don't get why the parameter order is `(v a n)` though, since you write `(setf (64-bit-word-array-32-bit-word-ref a n) v)` but maybe that is just how it is... I never wrote setf forms before.

Comment: @BitTickler: `setf` functions must have the value as the first argument because that's the only place you can safely add a new positional argument.  Imagine writing the definition of `(setf aref)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own little data structure e. g. using integers and `ldb`, `dpb` etc. under the hood: I'm thinking of new accessors like `byte-ref` and `word-ref`, and maybe looping constructs like `do-bytes` and `do-words`.  If you need bounds and checks thereof, you could add bounds in a wrapper structure.  Of course, this will not have the benefit of controlled pre-allocation (the size of the stored integer depends on the first set bit).

Comment: That sounds like an interesting little project in its own right. I never dabbled with the depths of SBCL. Maybe it is time to start and "invent" a new small set of datatypes...